# Issue linking c++ project together with CMake

Tags: c++

Been having a little issue figuring out how to link things together with CMake and I've been stuck for three days so far. No matter what I've tried I've been having an issue in having the function `returnThisClass()` being undefined no matter what I've tried.

On the minimum reproducible example in `headertest.cpp`, there is an undefined reference to the creation of the pointer, the same error is not present on my program despite everything appearing to be a direct copy.

My file structure is

```
    main.cpp
    src/
        headertest.cpp
        otherheader.cpp
    lib/
        headertest.h
        otherheader.h
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
    project(stackoverflowExample1 VERSION 0.1.0)
    
    include(CTest)
    enable_testing()
    
    add_library(aTest STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/otherheader.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/headertest.cpp)
    target_include_directories(aTest PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/)
    
    include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/)
    
    set(
        SOURCE_FILES 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/headertest.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/otherheader.cpp
        )   
    
    add_executable(stackoverflowExample1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
    
    target_link_libraries(stackoverflowExample1 PRIVATE aTest)
    
    set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
    set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
    include(CPack)
```

```cpp
main.cpp

    #include "lib/otherheader.h"
    int main() {
        doSomethingHere();
    }
```

headertest.h

```cpp
    namespace theTest {
    class foo1 {
        public:
            foo1();
        };
        foo1 * returnThisClass();
    }
```

otherheader.h

```cpp
    void doSomethingHere();
```

headertest.cpp

```cpp
    #include "../lib/headertest.h"
    
    theTest::foo1 * returnThisClass(){
        theTest::foo1 * aFoo1 = new theTest::foo1();
        return aFoo1;
    }
```

otherheader.cpp

```cpp
    #include "../lib/otherheader.h"
    #include "../lib/headertest.h"
    
    void doSomethingHere(){
        theTest::foo1 *foo1Ptr = theTest::returnThisClass();
    }
```

Comment: Your bug appears to be in the code not the CMake.

Comment: In the duplicate question [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/3440745) describes proper way for define member function in the source file.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
theTest::foo1 * returnThisClass(){
```

to

```
theTest::foo1 * theTest::foo1::returnThisClass(){
```

No idea about the CMake part, but the above is the first step.

Comment: The CMake part appears to be correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been running in circles for days trying to figure this out for it to be something so simple!